Is there a name for this condition on monomorphisms?
$\newcommand{\C}{}\newcommand{\D}{}\newcommand{\mon}{\hookrightarrow}$
Let $R: \C \to \D$ be a functor preserving monomorphisms. I define a mono $ι: A \mon B$ to be $R$-strong if for every mono $h: Z \mon B$ we have that $h$ factors through $ι$ iff $Rh$ factors through $Rι$.
In diagrams:

Is there a name for this condition?
Examples:

Let $V: \underline{\text{MGr}}\to \underline{\text{Set}}$ the vertex functor from multigraphs (aka "quivers") to sets.
(Multigraphs are just functors from $s, t: 1\rightrightarrows 0$ to $\underline{\text{Set}}$, so $V$ can be interpreted as the restriction to $0$)
There we see that a mono $A \mon B$ of multigraphs is $V$-strong iff it is a subgraph embedding – i.e. injective on vertices and edges, and contains all the edges between vertices in its image.
If $E$ is the edge functor instead, then a mono $A \mon B$ of multigraphs is $E$-strong iff it is a bijection on vertices and an injection on edges; i.e. it corresponds to giving a graph with the same vertex set but potentially less edges.
Any mono is $\mathrm{id}_\C$-strong
A mono is $\ast$-strong (with $\ast: \C \to \ast$ being the constant functor to the terminal category) if and only if it is an iso (plugging in $h=\mathrm{id}_B$ gives us a section for $ι$, and mono + split epi gives iso).

So in some sense, the notion of an $R$-strong monomorphism interpolates between very weak (just mono) and very strong (iso), depending on the choice of $R$.
It is also not hard to see that being $R$-strong is closed under composition.

To add to that: in general, split monos need not be $R$-strong monos for every $R$! If that were the case, then split monos were $ast$-strong, hence split epi, so they must be iso. However, in most categories split monos are not automatically isos, so this cannot be true.

Another very common example is the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Set}$, or any forgetful functor from an algebraic category for that matter. If we have two subgroups $Z,A$ of a group $B$ such that $Z \subseteq A$ as sets, then already $Z \subseteq A$ as groups. It does not hold for the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ (we would need to restrict to regular monos here).

The 'only if' direction is automatic by functoriality of $R$. Furthermore, given $w$, the lift $\tilde{w}$ is unique if it exists since $\iota$ is a monomorphism. Thus, $\iota$ being $R$-strong is the same as $\iota$ being an $R_{\text{mono}}$-cartesian morphism, where $R_{\text{mono}}\colon\mathcal{C}_{\text{mono}}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}_{\text{mono}}$ is the induced functor on subcategories consisting of monomorphisms.
Here are some general results about cartesian morphisms adapted to this scenario:

A monomorphism $f$ in $\mathcal{C}$ is an isomorphism if and only if it is $R$-strong and $Rf$ is an isomorphism. In particular, if every monomorphism in $\mathcal{C}$ is $R$-strong, then $R$ is conservative.

If $S\colon\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{E}$ is another monomorphism-preserving functor and $f$ is a monomorphism in $\mathcal{C}$ s.t. $Rf$ is $S$-strong, then $f$ is $R$-strong if and only if $f$ is $SR$-strong.

If $g,f$ are composable monomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ s.t. $g$ is $R$-strong, then $f$ is $R$-strong if and only if $gf$ is $R$-strong.



Thank you! I already stumbled upon properties two and three (since they hold for monos), but property 1 is new and it is very helpful to have a word attached to the concept.
